# LED on off delay (without an Arduino)

Tags: led, delay

I'm new to electronics but I want to put delay on a circuit without using an Arduino. I do have a Raspberry Pi 4, but I would like to try without using it. When I was looking on the internet I saw people using a capacitor, but they also used an Arduino.

What I want to make as something like a police light: every LED goes on and when it Is off, it starts the next LED.

This is what I have made on Tinkercad so far:

[image]

I want them to go on/off in the direction of the arrow:

[image]

Comment: To clarify with the pattern you want do you want the lights to alternate between each row or to have the lights turn on in a line?

Comment: hi @alfasierra, my apologies for the confusion. what I want to achieve is that the lights start at the bottom right, go to the left and then end at the top right again. I will edit a photo whit arrows in a few minutes

Comment: You could use a counter IC (which is available in tinkercad) and drive that with an oscillator.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out. Does somebody know what's wrong with my question? I'm new to stackExchange and I don't see why my question is bad...

Comment: Hi, @StefanWyss. I just found what you said I think: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/kYqcJtCTxXp-copy-of-led-blink-555-timer/editel?tenant=circuits, but that's not what I want. I want to but delay **between** the leds.

Comment: Then you may be want _variable duty cycle 555_ circuit

Comment: I do not have access to tinkercad, but a 555 is a good start for an oscillator. (BTW I don‘t think anything is wrong with your question, but you could be more precise: describe exactly what you want, e.g. First led on for 1sec, then first led off and 1sec pause, then second led on for 1sec, …)

Comment: thanks :), now I know in what direction I have to search. I have absolutly no idea how 555 circuits work, but I'll figure it out (I started with electronics one hour ago and I was pretty proud when the light went on :) )

Comment: There are too much literature about 555 IC, sometimes dilettantish, i advice to read books and datasheets. I think i guess that you want _running light_ circuit. This can be done in expandable way by ring oscillator based on transistors or 555 timers or smth. other, there are some variants in the net.

Comment: A running light circuit, that's what I was looking for! Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @tuurtje11 I started with electronics 20 years ago and I still have a lot more to learn than I already know. So keep up with it :-)

Comment: thanks @StefanWyss :)

Comment: For just 10 LEDs you can use a Johnson counter IC CD4017 and a clock generator to feed it. For longer chains you need either shift registers or binary counters followed by a demultiplexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first stage of a shift register solution

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTU5zP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need the switch SW1 to define an initial pattern to be moved around. Connect this signal to all following stages.

With the 4 inputs D0-D0 you configure the start pattern, here just the first LED on. In the following stages connect all 4 of them to GND or whatever you like.

Loop back Q3 of the the last register back to IN_RIGHT of the first to build a ring.

Use e.g. NE555 to create the moving clock signal CLK1. All stages need this clock signal.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have absolutly no idee what this means, but I'm learning :)